# Multi sourced search in WPF app

Tags: wpf, mvvm

If I’m using the MVVM pattern – this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for my WPF application

And my project requires a search function on different sources – say clients, accountants, cases.

What would be the best way to go about it so that I only have one search view and the search results shown in the ListView are ‘dynamic’ in that they could be result for clients or accountants or cases

Should I have a base search view model and specific view models for clients, accountants, cases that then somehow set as the datacontext for the search view

Or

try to build the grid dynamically in a code behind for the search and then somehow get the data back into the view model without the search view knowing about the view model.

**For clarification**

The searches are separate and will not need to be combined, I would only every return results for clients or accountants or cases.

Answer (score 1):

Map a generic View Model to whatever you are searching on.  The field names in the View Model will always be the same, i.e. `ID`, `Title`, `Description` or something like that.

For example, if you are searching for clients, map `ID` in your ViewModel to `ClientID` in your model, `Title` to `ClientName`, and `Description` to `ClientProfile`.

If you need to display different entities in the same search (e.g. clients and cases together), you will need to do multiple searches and UNION the results, or maintain a denormalized table of search descriptions.

Comment: added clarification to question

Answer (score 0):

I would build a grid for each search type case. e.g.

SEARCH RESULTS

## Accounting

result 1
result 2
result 3

## Cases

result 1
result 2
result 3

etc.